# How to disable SSL 2.0 on IIS 7.5?

Tags: ssl, iis-7.5

I've seen [this KB Article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/187498) which Microsoft put out covering how to remove SSL 2.0 on IIS 7.0 and earlier, but I can't find anything advising on how to do the same on IIS 7.5. The registry keys mentioned on that KB article are no longer in the registry.